# How to visualize the proof of $\operatorname{Col}(A^{H})\perp\operatorname{ker}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a diagram that I constructed using an online software :
$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

I am trying to understand how the row space of a matrix $A$ is orthogonal to the kernel space of $A$ since from the figure above, I am only able to point out that they are orthogonal. A more general theorem states that :

> For any two subspaces $U,V\subset\mathbb{C}^{n}$ are said to be orthogonal if any two vectors (and hence all vectors) $u\in U$ and $v\in V$ are orthogonal (i.e, $u^{H}v=0$)

I want to see geometrically how we can prove that the row space and the kernel space are orthogonal, the proof I've encountered goes as follow :

> Let $y\in\operatorname{Im}(A^{H})$ and $\widehat{y}\in\operatorname{ker}(A)$, we need to show that these two vectors are orthogonal. By definition, there exist $x$ such that  $y=A^{H}x$ and we also have that $A\widehat{y}=0$. Therefore :
> \begin{align*}
> y^{H}\widehat{y}&=(A^{H}x)^{H}\widehat{y}\;\;\;(a)\\
> &=x^{H}A\widehat{y}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(b)\\
> &=x^{H}\cdot0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(c)\\
> &=0
> \end{align*}

I have marked most of the steps of the proof by $(a),(b),$ and $(c)$ to indicate what I wish to visualize geometrically (say for $n=3$ thus the $3\operatorname{D}$ space) the projections, the transpose that will lead to $(c)$. Therefore, I would hope to expect an answer (if possible) that includes a geometric figure that fits the description of the proof and I would be extremely thankful.

Comment: I had already seen this graphical representation in the book "Introduction to linear algebra" by Gilbert Strang. Yours is especially nice!

Comment: Thank you very much! I am working on making a set of notes that include visualization for fundamental concepts of linear algebra

Comment: I have seen this proof of $N(A) = R(A^*)^{\perp}$: $$v \in N(A) \iff Av = 0 \iff \forall w, (Av, w) = 0  \iff \forall w, (v, A^*w) = 0 \iff v \in R(A^*)^{\perp}.$$ The step $Av = 0 \iff \forall w, (Av, w) = 0$ is the geometrically clear fact that the only vector orthogonal to every other vector is the $0$ vector. All the other steps are definitions.

Comment: See http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~stratos/research/orth/orth.html

Comment: In fact, teaching linear algebra to future engineers in my country (France), I found valuable to center all my explanations about this kind of relationships on the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) $A=U \Sigma V^T$, the matrices of which being more or less your rectangles...

Comment: I have found the link that you sent very useful! Indeed, when it comes to SVD and its diverse applications, this will attract the student's attention and builds up their curiosity in getting to know the secret behind the power of SVD @JeanMarie